# Send a Web Push (Chrome - GCM/FCM) Notification Directly, Based on User DB from OneSignal

Tags: push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging, onesignal, web-push

I am currently using OneSignal as the web-push provider, and would like to independently send a message to all of my users without depending and relying on their service (and obviously, the newly introduced costs).

OneSignal do let me download my entire user database including the GCM/FCM data.

Is the data provided sufficient to write a simple code that sends a message to a user from the database?

Here is an example of one row, with the fields they provide:

```
id
identifier
session_count
language
timezone
game_version
device_os
device_type
device_model
ad_id   tags
last_active
playtime
amount_spent
created_at
invalid_identifier
badge_count
lat
lon
rooted
ip
country web_auth
web_p256



7a2ad79c-4315-4b57-be2b-6cce179260ed
https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send/eNKyRHWMfMs:APA91bHMRVQk7gz27_JNTEsMnorqzd_JR6626eg43p-BhXmb1pslLX66db6w5-Aj--3GtpoCSVRHzMv2y_9tQlIVWKLakfmfLEAXy3rOsI4dvujHwou_X2wY9-TezBuDgST-o5A0fvo3
1
en
28800
56.0
5
Win32 Chrome
{}
2017-03-11 13:48:03.503015
0
0.00
2017-03-11 13:48:03.488008
t
0
f
125.60.243.173
PH
BFgB3OnEz3fGbNEbC/hiMA==
BMgmk8uppenwp1c5sPprEPHNYOu7n8yUjbAU7sKaImqldN+WnJosdZmUV/d4bv7RyQYiqu/z6KsJSn99B+A3IIA=
```

If it is possible, I would immensely appreciate being sent in a direction of a code example, in any language (preferably PHP, not necessarily), that could accomplish sending a message to this user as an example.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can send the notification to user using rest api of one signal .
Send a curl request on one signal with all details required -

```
$content      = array(
    "en" => '' // Your message content
);
$heading = array(
    "en" => ''  // Put heading according to you
);
$fields = array(
    'app_id' => ,  // Enter our app id here
    'filters' => array( array( "field" => "tag", "key" => "ad_id", "relation" => "=", "value" => 0) ), // You can use the ad_id data tag 
    "url" =>  '',  // Enter your landing url
    'contents' => $content,
    'headings' => $heading
);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8',
            'Authorization: Basic '.REST_API_KEY.''           // Your api key
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $response;
```

You can use data tag or plaer id in the realtion to send notification to filtered user.

Comment: I specifically mentioned I DO NOT want to send the notification via OneSignal, but to use the fields I have mentioned to send it DIRECTLY, not through the OneSignal API, to the user (e.g) via gcm/fcm